# How to set the value retrieve from SELECT statement into a variable when the result return is just 1 value

Tags: php, mysql

the fragment code

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {

    $query = "SELECT userid FROM user WHERE email = :email";
    $query_params = array(':email' => $_POST['email']);

    try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error Get User ID!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

    if ( false !== ($user = $stmt->fetch()))
    {
        $userid = $user['userid'];
    } 
    else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Why you come here!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
```

I want to ask is that after that `$row = $stmt->fetchAll();` How should I write the code of assigning the userid into $userid And php doesn't save the row result into a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[fetchAll()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) returns an array. so $row['userid'] will not be set. $row[0]['userid'] will.

Betterh would be to use:

```
if ( false !== ($user = $stmt->fetch()) )
{
  $userid = $user['userid'];
} else
{
  //user not found
}
```

What this code does, it tries to fetch a row fromt the statement. IF no row was found `->fetch()` returns a boolean `false`. As long as it doesn't return false, we have a row from the statement that is available in the `$user` var now :)

Comment: Thanks it works for me. But your code have some syntax error please check.

Comment: the if statement missed out a `)` also =)

Comment: Jiazzy, if you can't catch the syntax error yourself.... well, peace be with you.

Comment: >.< peace with me now

Answer (score 0):

```
$userID = isset($row['userid']);
```

Simply checks if $row['userid'] is set, i.e. it's a bool value.

Simply checking whether the array is empty or not will be sufficient for you to fetch the value straight away:

```
if(!empty($row))
{
    $userId = $row['userid'];
}
```

You need to make your question become more precise, if this isn't what you're asking for.